# Chaining Multiple operators in Javascript calculator

Tags: javascript

I cant seem to get my calculator to chain multiple operators together for example 5x5x5 should equal 125 but it just calculates 5x5 and will no longer calculate decimal numbers. Could anyone point me in the correct direction.

I have tried to assign the result to the firstNum but it seems to break the code.

```
button.forEach((button) =>
button.addEventListener('click', ()=> displayTotal(button.innerHTML)));

clearBtn.addEventListener('click', clear);

decmialBtn.addEventListener('click', appendDecimal);

functionBtn.forEach((button) => 
button.addEventListener('click', () => setOperator(button.innerHTML)));

equalsBtn.addEventListener('click', calculate)

let firstNum = "";                     
let secondNum = "";
let operatorSelection = "null";
let result = "";

function add(a, b){
    return a + b
}

function subtract(a,b){
return a - b
}

function divide (a,b)
{
return a / b
}

function times (a,b){
return a*b
}


function operator(operator, numa, numb) {
     switch(operator){
         case '+':
             return add(numa, numb);
             break;

         case '-':
             return subtract(numa, numb);
             break;
        
        case '/':
             return divide(numa,numb);
             break;

        case '*':
            return times(numa,numb)
            break;
     }
}

function displayTotal (number){
userDisplay.value += number;

}

function clear (){
    userDisplay.value = "";
}

function appendDecimal(){
    userDisplay.value += ".";
}


function setOperator(operator){
    firstNum = parseInt(userDisplay.value);
    operatorSelection = operator;
    result = firstNum;
    clear()
     }


     
function calculate(){
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    secondNum = parseInt(userDisplay.value);
    result = operator(operatorSelection, firstNum, secondNum);
    userDisplay.value = result;
    
[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple JS calculator you could use the eval() function and it will handle all the operators for you taking PEMDAS in consideration, but you have to ensure the inpput is valid or it you won't work.

I have one on my Github if want an example:
https://github.com/gustavo-shigueo/calculator

Note: don't worry about the regexes I used, they are there just to prevent the user from typing stuff that would break the calculator

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I would do it:

```
operations = [
    ["*", (a, b) => +a * +b],
    ["/", (a, b) => +a / +b],
    ["+", (a, b) => +a + +b],
    ["-", (a, b) => +a - +b],
];

const calc = calcString => {
    const split = [...calcString].reduce((prev, cur) => Number.isInteger(+cur) && Number.isInteger(+prev[prev.length - 1]) ? [...prev.slice(0, -1), prev[prev.length - 1] + cur] : [...prev, cur], [""]);
    operations.forEach(([operator, funct]) => {
        for (let i = 1; i < split.length - 1; i++) {
            if (split[i] === operator) {
                split[i - 1] = funct(split[i - 1], split[i + 1]);
                split.splice(i, 2);
                i--;
            }
        }
    })
    return split;
};
```

It doesn't support numbers with a dot/comma in them (e.g. 3.13) and no braces.

some explanation:

1. `const split`, I split the given string in numbers and operations, "3+45*4" would result in `["3", "+", "45", "*", "4"]`.
2. go over each operation in the given order to first do the "point calculation" and then + and -.
3. we go over the in 1. created array and look for our operation.
4. if we find one, we lool at the number before and after the operation and calculate the result given the 2 numbers and our operation type.
5. we overwrite those 3 elements with the result of our calculation.
6. we are done if all operations are done

I also have a more advanced version if you are interested